# Hive Time conversion

Tags: hive, hiveql

In the file we are getting time field as 1300,1400,1500...0000 in that I need to take  first two digits and subtract with 1 
example
time:1300 means exact time is 12
1 to 23 we can take it by using Substr(time,1,2)-1
In the case of 0000 hour how can we do that ?

Comment: Are you sure 1300 is really 12?  That looks like military time which would mean 1300 is 1:00.

Answer (score 0):

0000 is the same as 24 hrs? Then 
'case when substr(time,1,2)='00' then 23 else substr(time,1,2)-1 end'